# Получить индекс элемента относительно конкретного предка

Tags: jquery

Есть `div id="high"` с вложенными прямыми потомками `div attr="low"`, внутри каждого из которых есть множество параграфов, причем эти параграфы могут быть как прямые потомки для `div[attr]`, так и непрямые (например внутри таблиц).

Все эти параграфы я прогоняю через `.each().`

```
$('#high p').each()
```

Мне нужно получить индекс каждого параграфа относительно именно `closest('div')`, а не относительно родителя. В каких-то случаях `closest('div')` и является родителем, но не обязательно. Делать два `.each()` (сначала прогоняем каждый `div[attr]`, а в нем каждый p) кажется глупостью.

Наверняка же есть какое-то элегантное решение. Если это так, то подскажите, как сделать правильно.

Comment: добавь пример разметки и ожидаемый результат для нее

Answer (score 0):

Ну получается так... если только на jQuery...

```js
$('div[attr="low"]').each( function(){
  $(this).find('p').each( function(index){ 
    $(this).text( 'Мой индекс — ' + index );
  });
});
```

```css
div[attr="low"] {border: 1px solid red; margin: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="high">
  <div attr="low">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <span><p></p></span>
    <div><p></p></div>
  </div>
  <div attr="low">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <span><p></p></span>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

На чистом JS это можно организовать так:

```js
let low = document.querySelectorAll('div[attr="low"]');
for( let i = 0; i < low.length; i++ ){
  /* перебрав все найденные low, на каждом круге находим теги 'p' внутри них */
  let p = low[i].getElementsByTagName('p');
  for( let u = 0; u < p.length; u++ ){
    /* и снова перебираем уже найденные элементы 'p'... причем, на каждом круге
    u является конкретным числом, по совместительству - индексом элемента. */
    p[u].innerText = 'Мой индекс — ' + u;
  }

}
```

```css
div[attr="low"] {border: 1px solid red; margin: 5px;}
```

```html
<div id="high">
  <div attr="low">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <span><p></p></span>
    <div><p></p></div>
  </div>
  <div attr="low">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <span><p></p></span>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

В таком случае не факт, что на jQuery лучше)